# How to insert a div after another jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div in html page:

```
<div id="home">
</div>
```

Now I want to put another div under the div with id=home. I mean under the other div:

```
<div id="home">
</div>
<div id="new">
</div>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
var div=$('div');
var sopra=$('#home');
sopra.append(div);
```

But this code is wrong because put the new div in the div with `id=home`.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use **[.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)** function :

```js
var div=$('<div id="new">new</div>');
var sopra=$('#home');

$( sopra ).after( div );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home">home
</div>
```

Or also using **[.insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)** function :

```js
var div=$('<div id="new">new</div>');
var sopra=$('#home');

$( div ).insertAfter( sopra );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home">home</div>
```

> The `.after()` and `.insertAfter()` methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the content and target. With `.after()`, the selector expression preceding the method is the container after which the content is inserted. With `.insertAfter()`, on the other hand, the content precedes the method, either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and it is inserted after the target container.
>   Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Pure JavaScript**:
You can do it using [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) method:

```
document.getElementById('home').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="new"></div>');
```

`afterend` means after closing `</div>` tag.

---

Snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('home').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="new">new</div>');
```

```html
<div id="home">home</div>
```